# Sacar registros de Objeto y llenar tbody con Ajax JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy intentando sacar los registros del siguiente objeto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo abro muestra mis datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los estoy intentando sacar y meterlos a un tbody pero no me queda.

Este es mi código.

```
success: function(data) {
                var html = '';
                var i;
              for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                html += '<tr>' +
                  '<td>' + data.todas_calls[i].calldate + '</td>' +
                  '</tr>';
                  i++;
              }
                  $('#reg_tabla').html(html);
            },
```

> Datos que obtengo de los atributos del la bd

```
{

    accountcode: "financiera_arc-in",
    ​amaflags: "3",
    billsec: "5",
    calldate: "2018-05-01 08:46:43",
    channel: "SIP/TRK-4422901000-00001cf9",
    clid: "\"FINANCIERA ARC\" <4773256472>",
    ​​​dcontext: "virtual",
    disposition: "ANSWERED",​​​​
    dst: "564",
    dstchannel: "SIP/corp_lomas-500-00001cfa",
    duration: "25",
    lastapp: "Playback",
    lastdata: "vm1&vm_financiera_arc&vm2",
    src: "4773256472",
    userfield: ""

}
```

Comment: Podras copiar el json ?

Comment: son muchos registros por eso solo les pose captura

Comment: Almenos el head y 1 o 2  elementos del array

Comment: Listo ya puse los atrubutos del primer renglon.

Comment: Como te queda la variable html cuando termina el for ?

Comment: es decir antes de     $('#reg_tabla').html(html); ademas podrias mostrarnos el html de #reg_tabla

Comment: me muestra vacio con un alert

Comment: con un console.log(html);

Comment: llega como arreglo tridimencional ?

Comment: un objeto llamado todas_calls y adentro ya tiene los renglones con sus datos. Tome captura del data que recibo en el succes y le di un console.log

Comment: si quito el for y hago un console.log(data.todas_calls[0].calldate); si me imprime la fecha en la tabla pero no se como hacerle para que los saque de uno por uno un ciclo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta que recibes del backend es un objeto de la forma

```
{
 todas_calls: [
   {calldate:"2018-06-01", financiera: "Los 3 chanchitos"},
   {calldate:"2018-06-02", financiera: "La deuda"}
 ]
}
```

Vale decir, tienes que iterar no sobre `data` sino sobre `data.todas_calls`:

Supongamos que extraes el procesamiento a una función `dibujaTabla`

```
function dibujaTabla(data) {
  var html = '';
  data.todas_calls.forEach(function(fila) {
     html += '<tr>' +
             '<td>' + filas.calldate + '</td>' +
             '</tr>';         
  });
  $('#reg_tabla').html(html);
}
...
 success: function(data) {
   dibujaTabla(data);
 });
```

Hagamos un ejemplo con una respuesta explícita:

```js
function dibujaTabla(data) {
  var html = '';
  data.todas_calls.forEach(function(fila) {
    html += '<tr>' +
      '<td>' + fila.accountcode + '</td>' +
      '</tr>';
  });
  $('#reg_tabla').html(html);
}

var respuesta = {
  todas_calls: [{
      accountcode: "financiera1",
      billsec: 5,
      calldate: "2018-05-01 08:46:43",
      duration: 25
    },
    {
      accountcode: "financiera2",
      billsec: 45,
      calldate: "2018-05-02 14:46:43",
      duration: 38
    },
    {
      accountcode: "financiera3",
      billsec: 8,
      calldate: "2018-05-04 08:56:43",
      duration: 45
    },
    {
      accountcode: "financiera4",
      billsec: 15,
      calldate: "2018-05-05 18:46:43",
      duration: 15
    }
  ]
};

dibujaTabla(respuesta);
```

```css
#reg_tabla {
border:1px solid;
}

#reg_tabla td {
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="reg_tabla">

</table>
```

Pero sería una molestia tener que escribir de antemano cada columna de la tabla, por lo cual sería más eficiente tomar los campos del primer registro y usarlos como diccionario (asumiendo que todos los registros tengan los mismos campos):

```js
function dibujaTabla(data,campos) {
  var tabla = $('#reg_tabla');
  tabla.empty(); // vaciamos la tabla;
  var cabecera=jQuery('<tr></tr>');
  campos.forEach(function(campo) {
    cabecera.append('<td>'+campo+'</td>');
  });
  
  tabla.append(cabecera);
  
  data.todas_calls.forEach(function(objeto) {
    var fila=jQuery('<tr></tr>');
    campos.forEach(function(campo) {
        fila.append('<td>'+objeto[campo]+'</td>');
    });
    tabla.append(fila);
  });
}

var respuesta = {
  todas_calls: [{
      accountcode: "financiera1",
      billsec: 5,
      calldate: "2018-05-01 08:46:43",
      duration: 25
    },
    {
      accountcode: "financiera2",
      billsec: 45,
      calldate: "2018-05-02 14:46:43",
      duration: 38
    },
    {
      accountcode: "financiera3",
      billsec: 8,
      calldate: "2018-05-04 08:56:43",
      duration: 45
    },
    {
      accountcode: "financiera4",
      billsec: 15,
      calldate: "2018-05-05 18:46:43",
      duration: 15
    }
  ]
};

// Obtienes los nombres de columnas:

var columnas = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(respuesta.todas_calls[0]);

dibujaTabla(respuesta,columnas);
```

```css
#reg_tabla {
border:1px solid;
}

#reg_tabla td {
border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="reg_tabla">

</table>
```